# Sharepoint Online - events page

Tags: sharepoint-online

i need to make different events page for a site collection . How to do that because in every page its showing me the same events which i have created previously ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that with "events page" you mean inserting an events web part on a modern site page. You can configure the web part and define which events list it looks at, and also which category to include. That should give you sufficient handles to configure different events web parts to show different events.

Click the Edit icon to for the web part, then set the options in the panel on the right.

[image]

[image]

You need to configure the web part on the NYC page to only show events that pertain to NYC . You can do that by classifying your events. SharePoint cannot read your mind. But it can read the Category field of an event. You need to tag each event with a category for NYC or the other states. Then you can configure the web part on the NYC page to show only events with the NYC category.

Comment: Actually i was planning to make 4 different event pages . each showing different events . so in nyc page it should show nyc events and on London page it must show London events . but itz showing the same events i have previously entered in nyc page !! i want to have different set of events for London . and yes they are in the same site collection

Comment: So, how did you configure the Events web part? What is it looking at? What are the filter settings???

Comment: so basically i created a quick link naming NYC which means if i click this quick link it will take me to a page abt the vents in nyc. likewise i created 2 different quick links for other states so show me their events but i  they show me the same events which i have previously entered in nyc .How to change that ? How to make different event pages so that it can show me different events in different pages ?

Comment: Well, you created a page or three. Fine. Each page has an events web part. Also fine. How is SharePoint supposed to know which events you want to show on the NYC page? You need to configure the web part on the NYC page to only show events that pertain to NYC . You can do that by classifying your events.  SharePoint cannot read your mind.  But it can read the **Category** field of an event. You need to tag each event with a **category** for `NYC` or the other states. Then you can configure the web part on the NYC page to show only events with the `NYC` category. Get it now?

Comment: oh okkay i'll try that ! Thank you !!

Comment: it worked !! thank you !! @teylyn

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Please finish the paperwork and mark the answer as explained in the [tour].